# How do I implement this similarity measure in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, math

I tried implementing the distance measure shown in the image, in Python as such:

```
import numpy as np

A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]
B = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 2]

A = np.asarray(A).flatten()
B = np.asarray(B).flatten()

x = np.sum(1 - np.divide((1 + np.minimum(A, B)), (1 + np.maximum(A, B))))
print("Distance: {}".format(x))
```

but after testing, it doesn't seem to be the right approach. The maximum value returned if there's no similarity at all between the given vectors should be 1, with 0 as perfect similiarity. A and B in the image are both vectors with size m.

Edit: forgot to add that I ignored the part for min(A, B) < 0 as that wont ever happen for my intentions

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. First, we create a matrix `AB` by stacking the columns and calculate the minimum vector `AB_min` and maximum vector `AB_max` out of that. Then, we compute `D` as you defined it, making use of `numpy.where` to specify the two conditions. After that, we sum the elements to get the `D_proposed` as you defined it. It gives a value of `0.9` for this example.

```
import numpy as np

A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]
B = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 2]

AB = np.column_stack((A,B))

AB_min = np.min(AB,1)
AB_max = np.max(AB,1)
print AB_min
print AB_max

D = np.where(AB_min >= 0.,\
        1. - (1. + AB_min) / (1. + AB_max),\
        1. - (1. + AB_min + abs(AB_min)) / (1. + AB_max + abs(AB_min)))
print D

D_proposed = np.sum(D)
print D_proposed
```

Comment: I tried with a few other values like: 

     A = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
     B = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]

Which returns  a distance of 0.5, with bigger values the like 5 vs 1, it returns a 6. My understanding was that it will return a value between 0 and 1 for any case.

Comment: The values of `D` are all between 0 and 1, following your definition. Probably you have to divide `D_proposed` by its size to get that behavior.